# Android emulator error: user data image is used by another emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I Got this type of error when Run a program on emulator.

ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting

Answer (score 1):

Exit from eclipse and ADB , and watch your task manager that how much emulator is running. is there anymore then one then close it and restart the eclipse and start ADB.

Answer (score 0):

reboot your computer, this happens when the ADB bridge crashes sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that stopping and restarting the emulator (and perhaps Eclipse) will fix it - less drastic than rebooting.